# Instagram Approval

Tags: instagram-api

I was tasked to develop a web application that has an instagram module in it. The module is supposed to do the following:
1. Display the logged in user timeline
2. Allow user to like and unlike a photo
3. Allow user to comment on a photo

My question is: will the app get approved upon submission or will it be rejected  because it replicates original features?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get user timeline any more, it was deprecated June 1, 2016.

You probably wont get approval since you can do the same on instagram.com, why dont you just use that?
If your app is doing something significant that cannot be done with Instagram app, then there is a chance you will get approved